# Powershell Retrieve-Job gives "cannot index into null array error"

Tags: windows, powershell, start-job

I am trying to test if two PC's are connected by using the following script

```
$array ='PC1','PC2'


for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++)  {

     Start-Job –Name TestConnection$i –Scriptblock {

            if(test-connection $array[$i] -count 1 -quiet){
               write-host Success
            }

            else { write-host No connection
            }

    }

}
```

When I try to do Receive-Job for either one I get "Cannot index into a null array".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say neither `$array` nor `$i` exist in the context of the scriptblock, so that is where the null array error comes from. The `receive-job` part sounds like it's working properly

Comment: I thought since `$array` is outside of the block it would be available??

Comment: Are you able to echo the value inside the scriptblock?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry I'm pretty new to this..

Comment: Read `Get-Help Start-Job`. Powershell jobs run in a separate thread and essentially have their own environment. That means code in the `ScriptBlock` is distinct, it doesn't have access to anything within the script that launched it, unless you explicitly pass it as arguments. What I was saying is to try and do a `echo $i` in the scriptblock. When you receive the output you'll see it is empty.

Comment: @arco444 ++ but not even in separate threads, separate *processes*

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, I wasn't sure or not if extra processes were spawned for jobs.

Comment: @arco444 Thanks I will try this later and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the PC name as an argument, as the array does not exist in the context of the script block, like this:

```
$array ='PC1','PC2'

for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++) {

    Start-Job –Name TestConnection –Scriptblock { 
        param($pcName)

        if(Test-Connection $pcName -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            Write-Host Success
        } else {
            Write-Host No connection
        }           
    } -ArgumentList $array[$i]
}
```

Comment: You also need to make sure the job is complete before you do receive-job (at least to see all the output). You can use Wait-Job or check the JobStateInfo.state of the job (which you get back from start-job)

Comment: OK this has worked for me ,thanks. So my understanding is that `param($pcName)` takes whats in `-ArgumentList` ???

Comment: that's right, you use the ArgumentList to pass in parameters, the value of which are assigned to the variable in the param() section, you then reference those parameters in your script block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $i (and any other variables) via -ArgumentList through the Start-Job Cmdlet since your script block is running in an entirely different powershell host and doesn't have access to anything inside the shell that started the job.

Even though your script block exists inside the original code, Powershell does not expand any variables in it until it's executing the code in the other host.  You can define param() at the beginning of your script block to use the variable you pass via -ArgumentList

Comment: Hi Mike. How does this differ from steoleary's answer? It sounds the same as his answer.

Comment: steoleary's wasn't posted when I had started my reply